# Secret Field not be imported when using prefect

Tags: pydantic, prefect

ImportError: cannot import name 'SecretField' from 'pydantic'

Hi guys, i having some trouble when using prefect
I was installed prefect, activate venv and i had this :D
ImportError: cannot import name 'SecretField' from 'pydantic'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prefect'
Someone help me :((

Answer (score 0):

What version of Prefect are you using?

If you can upgrade Prefect and its dependencies, that should fix it.

If using pip, run `pip install -U prefect`

Recent Prefect versions specify a pinned Pydantic version, which should resolve the issue.